# How to create a Scala jar file (in Eclipse) on Windows

Tags: eclipse, windows, scala

I'm trying to create a Scala jar file on Windows (in Eclipse if possible). However, Most of the solutions I found so far seem to be for Unix or Linux machines (and a little too complicated). So, I would like to know if there is any way I can create Scala jar file on Windows machine specifically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "create a Scala jar file" - I assume that you mean you want to compile a Scala program into a jar file. A very common (some might say 'standard') way to compile Scala programs on any platform is to use sbt (http://www.scala-sbt.org/). If you are spending any time with Scala it's certainly worth learning to use sbt, and basic usage is very simple.

There's an sbt plugin for Eclipse too (https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).

If you are using sbt you would just need to enter:

```
sbt package
```

at a command line. This will compile your Scala code and create a jar file. If you want to create a jar file with all the dependencies bundled within then you can use the sbt assembly plugin (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and then:

```
sbt assembly
```

I use both of these sbt commands (package and assembly) on both Windows and Linux environments fairly regularly and they work well on both platforms.